# Store Value in Database With For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Here's my code: you will automatically understand what it does

```
<form method="post">
    Enter Your Numbers
    <input type="number" name="number" min="1" max="10" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    for ($x=0; $x<=$number; $x++) {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"tbno".$x."\">";
    }
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit1\">";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("bookabook");

}
?>
```

Here's my question: I want to store the textbox values in database, but I don't know how to do this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("bookabook");
   //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE
}
```

Can anyone tell me please?

Comment: Are all both of your php statements from the first code section called in sequence or is there something that happens between them? What does your database schema look like? What does the data you are collecting look like? We can't really help you without the code you have provided. If you could either give us your schema or a sqlfiddle, that would be great.

Comment: I just want to store the textbox values in my database call bookabook and name of the table book_name

Comment: THis link will help you along a bit: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: I know how to add Values in Database i want to know how can i add the value of textbox that is created by Loop

Comment: (1) your generated inputs are not inside a form, (2) instead of appending a number at the end, make them an array -> `name=\"tbno[]\"` as it will be easier to parse on form submit, and (3) what have you tried? there are thousands of database insert examples here on SO, including using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`

Comment: Bro If i know how to Do this With Array i can do this my Own i dont know how to do this thats why i am asking

Comment: For your form to work you need 2 files: one with <form> <textbox name= 'yo'>Howzit</textbox></form>

Comment: in the second file: you have $yo = $_POST['yo']);

Comment: $number = $_POST['number'];
    echo "<form methor=\"POST\">";
    for ($x=0; $x<=$number; $x++) {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"tbno".$x."\">";
    }
   
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit1\">";
    echo "</form>";

Ok Done Now what to Do ?

Comment: and then your SLQ query will be: INSERT INTO books (BookName)
VALUES ('$yo')

Comment: If you use `name=\"tbno[]\"` instead of `name=\"tbno".$x."\"` then you can use a loop similar to the one you used to create them -> `for ($x=0; $x<count($_POST['tbno']); $x++) { //insert $_POST['tbno'][$x] }` or more simply -> `foreach($_POST['tbno'] as $tbno){ //insert $tbno }`

Comment: @Sean Can u Make the Code ?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: @MunnooHammad If you have a job posting, there's places on the internet for that. Not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a counter `$x` -> `name=\"tbno".$x."\"`, just set your inputs to an array -> `name=\"tbno[]\"`. Then on form submit you can easily loop through them using a `foreach` or `for` loop.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tbno']))
{
    //your db connection
    foreach($_POST['tbno'] as $tbno){
             //INSERT INTO tbl VALUE $tbno
    }
    echo 'INSERTED DATA';
}
?>

<form method="post">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['number']))
{
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    for ($x=0; $x<$number; $x++) {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"tbno[]\">";
    }
}
else 
{ ?>
    Enter Your Numbers<input type="number" name="number" min="1" max="10" />
<?php 
} ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I condensed your 2 forms into 1, as the only thing that changes the inputs, so there is less code.

Comment: Bro I am Working on it

Comment: Sean Bro Do u have Any Contact ID where i can Contact u ? Like Facebook ?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately I don't give out my personal contact info, especially on a public site. If you need additional help with this issue, either post another comment or update your question. If you need help on another issue/question, then post a link to the question. I am happy to help, but I prefer to keep it here on SO.

Comment: Now If i Want to Insert On 2 Columns How can i ? I Use Thhis Code but its not working 'foreach($_POST['tbno'] as $tbno and $_POST['bbno'] as $bbno) {
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('$tbno','$bbno')");
        
    }'

Comment: Is `$_POST['bbno']` built the same/similar way to `$_POST['tbno']`? If so, use the key to link them together -> `foreach($_POST['tbno'] as $key => $tbno) { $bbno = $_POST['bbno'][$key]; mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('$tbno','$bbno')"); }`

Answer (score 1):

```
# HTML
echo "<input type='text' name='tbno[]' value='$x'>";
# PHP
$array = $_POST[tbno];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
echo "$key = $value<br/>";
}
```

Comment: +1. a little nitpicky, but `$array = $_POST[tbno];` should be `$array = $_POST['tbno'];` as string array keys should be quoted to prevent php from saying `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant tbno - assumed 'tbno' (line 4)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is an insert statement. I'm not sure I understand the code, but I understand the objective. All you need to do is create an insert(like below) statement in the for-loop that loops through the books, etc..

```
$number = trim($_POST['number']);

$numberOfBooks = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlDatabseConnectionObject,$numberOfBooks); //variable to be inserted in the database

$insertQuery = sprintf("INSERT INTO <table_name> VALUES('%s'",$numberOfBooks)); //statement to be executed

$insertResults = $mysqlDatabseConnectionObject->query($insertQuery); //execute the query

print_r($insertResults); //printing the query execution results
```

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. What you're doing here with manual escaping and `sprintf` is a gigantic hack.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("bookabook");

    $values = "";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $inputValue){
       $values.="(".$inputValue."),";
    }
    $SQL_string = "INSERT INTO mitabla(micampo) VALUES $values";
    mysql_query($SQL_string,$link);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: This is hazardously bad due to a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) and a lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).